# How to delete WordPress author pages in a site migration?

Tags: seo, wordpress

Our company is doing a site migration. I want to delete the pages that do not have SEO value for us.

A URL that goes to the author's page contains some articles that I don't want to lose.

From the other side as I know in deleting a webpage you should firstly remove all the internal links.

I can not find this URL in WordPress in order to delete all the links to the articles and then delete it. What should I do?

Consider that these articles are in other pages like in blog as well.

Comment: Are you migrating to WordPress, away from WordPress, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Author pages are generally generated by author.php which can be found or created in the root folder of the WordPress theme that are you using.

Using `noindex` in either the meta or header response will inform all search engines not to index those pages. This can be done many ways and here is some of the top of my head:

***Header.php Method (easiest)***

Edit header.php and add the below code just after `<head>` and before `</head>`

```
<?php if (is_author()) {
    echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow" />';
} ?>
```

***Plugin Method***

There are several WordPress plugins on the WP library that will do this without any coding, for example [Yoast SEO](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/how-do-i-noindex-urls/) allows you to select noindex on a large range of page types.

***Robots.txt Method***

Using the disallow of `/author/` will inform search engines not to index this content.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /author/
```

***.htaccess Redirect Method***

I do not recommend this method but for some people they may want to use a redirect, like so:

`RewriteRule ^author/(.*) /blog/ [R=301,NC,L]`

***Virtual Host File***

```
<Location "/author/*">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow"
</Location>
```

***Just because you can doesn't mean you should!***

Author pages improve UX, they are users to filter through content by author which is very helpful, you should never use no-index on useful pages, therefore I recommend that you only use no-index on author pages with no posts.

Yoast SEO I believe has this option and the [WordPress stack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) is the place to go for helping develop your code so that, for example it should be possible to use a `<` less than or greater than `>` PHP operator with is_author(), if you have no idea what I'm talking about then just go ahead and make your life easier by using a plugin.